# Regarding 12057 RTC accuracy

Tags: real-time-clock

i am beginner in embedded programming. In my project i am using ISL12057ibz RTC, we connected an crystal VT-200-f to it with 5 pf of parallel capacitance .the stray capacitance of the board is varying from 7-8 pf (we can't change the PCB designing). in this condition RTC delay is increased by 3 sec. after every 24 hours.
please help me so that i can reduce the time delay problem.

Comment: You might want to improve the tags associated with your question. Somehow the post has a tag that is for a software Application Lifecycle Management app. By having a good set of tags, you will increase the audience for your question.